# Sequelize association from array of JSONs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to make an association in sequelize from a model with a column which is array of json

```
timeLine:[
    {
        userId:2,
        status:Started
    },
    {
        userId:3,
        status:Ended
    }
]
```

timeLine is a column in case table.
I want a cases which was started by given user.

Comment: It is called one-to-many relationship in sequelize. Checkout the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#one-to-many-associations--hasmany).

Comment: one-to-many works if we had userId column in case table. 
but I have timeline column in case table, which has json of user_id

Comment: Ok, let me say that, I need more information to figure out what you need or what you're trying to accomplish. So please add code for your `Timeline` table, `User` table and `Case` table.

Comment: i want all the cases which was started with users with id [2,3,4] lets say ...

Answer (score 0):

On a high level you need to create two models.

1. User
2. Case

User would have a foreign key id to the Case table.
Next in the Case model, establish a one-to-many relationship so that you can do a Case.timeline to pull up the array of users.

```
// example of how to establish the one-to-many relationship
Case.hasMany(models.user, {
  as: 'timeline',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'caseId',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Comment: It would not work. Timeline is a json field. User doesn't have a caseId.